# Ionic Bundle ID Still Causing Issues After Changing

Tags: android-studio, config, ionic4, google-play-console, bundle-identifier

Hi I really need help and am on a time crunch, so I'm willing to try everything I haven't already. I'm trying to upload an app to the Google Play store and I keep receiving this error.

[image]

The crazy thing is that in my config.xml file I have changed this, and the problem still persists. I have rebuilt the project, signed it with Android Studio, tried to uninstall and reinstall plugins, reinstalled the node_modules folder. I even looked into the gradle files to see if the bundle id was stored elsewhere(couldn't find it). But no matter what I do I keep getting the exact same error in the Google Play store repeatedly. I have even deleted and started a new application in the play store. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Is there somewhere else where the config filed is stored? Or should I just copy my files over to another Ionic folder or something drastic like that? I haven't found anything else online or on this forum that has solved my problem. Please help if you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have Capacitor integrated into your app? If so check the appId value in capacitor.config.json

If you did not initialize Capacitor after integrating it into your app, the configuration object will look like this

```
{
   "appId": "io.ionic.starter",
   "appName": "<your-app-name-here>",
   "bundledWebRuntime": false,
   "npmClient": "npm",
   "webDir": "www",
   "cordova": {}
}
```

If you do need to update this object, the Capacitor [docs](https://capacitor.ionicframework.com/docs/getting-started/with-ionic) say to

> Note: Use the native IDEs to change these properties after initial configuration.

Hope this helps.